# Multithreaded is slower than singlethreaded

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, cpu, cpu-usage

It is not faster - it's also much slower .

I have cpu with 4 core.

==================================================================

```
Private Sub btn_Singelthreaded_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Singelthreaded.Click

    Dim Num As Long
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    Dim TimeAvrg As Double
    For i = 0 To 8

        Num = 0
        sw.Restart()
        Do Until Num > 500000000 '500,000,000
            Num += 1
        Loop


        TimeAvrg += sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
        'sw.Stop()
    Next
    Console.WriteLine($"[Singelthreaded] Avrg Time: {TimeAvrg / 8}{Environment.NewLine}")


End Sub

Private NumThrd As Long
Private swThrd As New Stopwatch
Private Sub btn_Multithreaded_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Multithreaded.Click


    Dim T1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ForLoop) : T1.Start()
    Dim T2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ForLoop) : T2.Start()
    Dim T3 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ForLoop) : T3.Start()

End Sub


Private Sub ForLoop()
    Dim TimeAvrg As Double
    For i = 0 To 2
        TimeAvrg = 0
        NumThrd = 0
        swThrd.Start()
        Do Until NumThrd > '500,000,000
            NumThrd += 1
        Loop
        TimeAvrg += swThrd.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
        'swThrd.Stop()

    Next
    Console.WriteLine($"[Multithreaded] Avrg Time: {TimeAvrg / 3}{Environment.NewLine}")
End Sub
```

Result:
[Singelthreaded] Avrg Time: 2.1183545

[Multithreaded] Avrg Time: 11.6677879333333

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's considerably faster.  If I understand your question, you're trying to measure the elapsed time of 9 iterations in one thread versus breaking up those 9 iterations into 3 threads, each with 3 iterations.  To do that you can create a form level for the stopwatch.

```
Private totTime As New Stopwatch
```

and then code your button clicks as follows:

```
Private Sub btn_Singelthreaded_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Singelthreaded.Click

    Dim Num As Long
    totTime.Restart()
    For i = 0 To 8
        Num = 0
        Do Until Num > 500000000
            Num += 1
        Loop
    Next
    totTime.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(totTime.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)

End Sub


Private Sub btn_Multithreaded_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Multithreaded.Click

    totTime.Restart()
    Dim T1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ForLoop) : T1.Start()
    Dim T2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ForLoop) : T2.Start()
    Dim T3 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ForLoop) : T3.Start()

    T3.Join()

    totTime.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(totTime.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)

End Sub

Private Sub ForLoop()

    Dim Num As Long
    For i = 0 To 2
        Num = 0
        Do Until Num > 500000000
            Num += 1
        Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `btn_Singelthreaded_Click` and `ForLoop` subs are not equal. In `btn_Singelthreaded_Click` you use `sw.Restart()`, but in `ForLoop` there is `swThrd.Start()`. I think its a clue to your problem. For example, the execution time of `ForLoop` is 2. Then, through there is no `swThrs.Restart()`, you'll get `TimeAvrg = 2 + 4 + 6` and at the end you'll get `TimeAvrg/3 = 4`.

The second, what is that mean `Do Until NumThrd > '500,000,000`? Where is the actual number you compare with?

The third. You should use local stopwatch for each `ForEach` sub run. I don't think that Stopwatch is thread safe since there is no mentions about thread safity of Stopwatch class in the MSDN docs.

The fourth. At line `NumThrd += 1` you get [Race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), so `ForLoop` runs longer than it can. You should read about one.

And the last, NumThrd is not synchonized. If you don't use any memory bariers here, then the compiler can (and I think it must) use processor registers for you NumThrd counter. Of course cpu cores can't see changes in foreign registres, so no cooperation can be reached in that scenario.